# How to test list of inputs with PyTest in a sentinel while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I've been trying to test a list of inputs in Pytest using this function

```
def test_play_hand():                                                               
    word_list = load_words()                                                        
    hand = {'e': 2, 'u': 1, 'g': 1, 'm': 1, 'b': 1, 't': 1}                         
    inputs = ['gum', 'beet', '.']                                                   

    with mock.patch('builtins.input', return_value= next(iter(inputs))):                                                                      
        assert play_hand(hand, word_list) == 0
```

The function play_hand run a sentinel-based while loop that gets a dictionary, then asks users for a string input.

If the input is a `.`, the loop ends.

Otherwise, if the loop gets a string, it will check the hand and for the available characters and remove the characters used in the string from the hand.

The test works when mock.patch gets only one input.

How can you implement the test using a list or multiple inputs for testing?

Without iter() it gives an error of inputs not iterable and with iter() it just freezes.

I appreciate any input.

Edit: Forgot to mention that play_hand returns an int

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer.

```
def test_play_hand():                                                               
    word_list = load_words()                        
    hand = {'e': 2, 'u': 1, 'g': 1, 'm': 1, 'b': 1, 't': 1} 
    inputs = ['gum', 'beet', '.']                                      

    with mock.patch('builtins.input', side_effect = inputs) :                       
        assert play_hand(hand, word_list) == 12
```

I had to replace `return_value` with `side_effect` to run all the inputs in the test.

Link: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html